# How to detect a 16 bit overflow with CCS

Tags: c, optimization, microprocessors

I have to add numbers with this script:

```
for(i=1; i<1000 ;i++)
sum=sum+i;
```

it will overflow at 32768 and after that it goes to -32768 because it cant exceed the 16 bit limit.

i want to count the overflows with an int c.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check if sum > sum + i

Comment: This only works for unsigned types. For signed types the result of overflow is undefined. Some compilers use that knowledge to always optimize `x + y > x` to true when y is known to be positive. http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html#signed_overflow

Comment: That makes sense. Maybe its better to check `INT_MAX - sum < i`. This only works under the conditions that both i and sum is positive.